# Getting response error for Google Maps API if key and SHA1 are correct in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps API v2. I have quadruple checked that the API key and SHA1 for my app are correct. I have a drop down menu that when one of the items is clicked, the map shows the markers for that item. I had used this before and it was working fine but now it isn't. I deleted the old keys and created new ones thinking it would fix the problem but it hasn't. I am calling this url to get the necessary response:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.9782618,-120.1863181&radius=10000&query=walmart&key={MY_KEY}`

But when I click on a button to call that url, the response that is returned is this:

```
 {"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
       Request received from IP address {BLOCKED}, 
       with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],
       "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

Which can't be possible if the API key and SHA1 are correct. I have been at this for hours trying to figure out what the problem is and I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me. If I set the restriction on the API to an Android app then it should recognize the fingerprint provided and work just fine. I've tried running it in debug and release.

**NOTE:** The IP address has been blocked here for security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google API console, check to see if the key you are using is restricted to Android apps.  Even though you are making that call from an Android app, you are accessing the Places API as if you were a browser by calling an endpoint directly instead of using the [Android Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/).  You will need to either make a separate browser key for direct http calls or use the Android API.

Comment: I have it restricted to Android but it still returns the same access denied response

Comment: You need one that is NOT restricted to android, because you are making the call like a browser, not and android app.

Comment: I tried it without any restrictions as well to no avail 

Comment: I have about 12 different buttons that once clicked bring up the locations for that specific query. For example, of they click the Walmart button, it shows all Walmarts in the area. Am I not calling this correctly? I followed a tut for this

Comment: That's weird.  Have you enabled "Google Places API Web Service" in your console?

Comment: Yes. I'm completely stumped by this. This should be working.

Comment: That is the last of my suggestions, because a common mistake is to enable Places for Android, but not Places API for Web Service.  Other common mistakes -- using a restricted key as already mentioned, and typos in key (failing to copy the whole key, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130459/discussion-between-iagreen-and-steve-c).

Comment: I added a comment in chat, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

For Google map you can simply use `Api Key` now. No need to enter sha key. Also for Google Places api first we used `Brower key` but for now `Api key` is enough for Goggle Places api too.

Just add your api key. I checked it with my own api key and its working fine. Add yours.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.9782618,-120.1863181&radius=10000&query=walmart&key=YOUR_API_KEY

[image]

Note: One more thing don't write your api key directly in manifest. First declare it in `string.xml` then use it.

for e.g.

```
           <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_geo_api_key" />
```

Comment: I've tried with just the API key and no SHA1 fingerprint. Still gives same response.

Comment: also check your manifest. don't declare directly api key in your manifest. check my edited answer.

Comment: I have the meta-data already. The map loads just fine. It's when I try to call that url with the same api key as the map or a different one I still get the error that the app is not authorized to use the api key :/

Comment: I've tried the api key with no restrictions also and still same response. I have no idea what the issue is and its getting very frustrating.